# To use Tesseract4Android, how to update build.gradle.kts instead of build.gradle?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am trying to use Tesseract4Android for my Android application, a library from: https://github.com/adaptech-cz/Tesseract4Android.

I encountered a problem when I tested it with Kotlin:

```
Failed to resolve: cz.adaptech.tesseract4android:tesseract4android:4.7.0
```

Here are my settings:

`settings.gradle.kts`:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven {
            setUrl("https://jitpack.io")
        }
    }
}
```

`build.gradle.kts`:

```
dependencies { 
    // ...
    implementation("cz.adaptech.tesseract4android:tesseract4android:4.7.0")
}
```

Thanks in advance!

I've checked similiar questions but failed to find the reason.
I've googled for this issue but failed to find the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the correct repository to the `build.gradle.kts` file. The ones in `settings.gradle.kts` `pluginManagement` are for the resolution of plugins.

```
repositories {
   maven { setUrl("https://jitpack.io") }
}
```

Comment: Besides `pluginManagement`, there's `dependencyResolutionManagement` ...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution like below. It works correctly.

releaseImplementation("com.github.adaptech-cz:Tesseract4Android:4.7.0")

Comment: This so called "solution" provides little meaning, because it will lack in the debug build.

Comment: yes, it does not work. I've added aar file instead of using jitpack

Answer (score 0):

Try another notation for property `url`:

```
import org.gradle.api.initialization.resolve.RepositoriesMode

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven(url = 'https://jitpack.io')
    }
}
```

Then it should find:

```
implementation 'cz.adaptech/tesseract4android:4.7.0'
```